# Why Are HashMaps Implemented Using Powers of Two?

Tags: java, hashmap

My question is why hashmap bucket size is power of 2 and I have gone through many answers on stackoverflow but i am still not convinced. Reasons are:

1. I have read that having capacity as power of 2 makes & operation more efficient to calculate index so my question how exactly it is useful here. I can have size which might be power of 3 , I can still perform & operation like this (hash)&(length-1) so why exactly it should be power of 2 ?
2. Also if the capacity is not power of 2 why i need to do remainder operation?

Comment: `(hash)&(length-1)` will not give you the correct answer if `length` is not a power of 2. If `length` is 3 then `(hash)&(length-1)` can only equal 0 or 2, so the bucket at index 1 would be unusable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you subtract 1 from a number which is a power of 2, what you get is a number whose binary representation is all 1. E.g. 16 is a power of 2. If you subtract 1 from it, you get 15, whose binary representation is 1111. Now, if you do a bitwise AND of any number with 1111, you're going to get the last 4 bits of the number which, in other words, is equivalent to the modulo of the number by 16 (Division operation is usually an expensive operation. Hence, bitwise operation is usually preferred over division). These last 4 bits will evaluate to any number from 0 to 15 which are the indexes of your underlying array.

You could make the size 17 instead. In that case, after subtracting 1 from it, you'd get 16 which is 10000 in binary. Now you do a bit wise AND of a number with 16, you'll lose all bits of the number except the 5th bit from the end. So, regardless of the number you take, the array index will be either 16 or 0. That means you'd have lot of collisions, which in turn means poor performance. Instead of O(1) for retrieval, you'd need O(log n), because when collision occurs, all the nodes in a given bucket are going to be stored in a red black tree. Not only that. In case you are using a `ConcurrentHashMap` in a multithreaded environmemt, you'd experience lot of synchronizations, because all the new additions will end up in a very small number of buckets (only two - 0 and 16 in the above case) and when you add new nodes in a bucket that already has other nodes, the bucket will be locked to avoid data inconsistancies due to modifications by multiple threads. Therefore, other threads trying to add new nodes need to wait until the current thread release the lock.

Finally, I should also mention that the Java `HashMap` implementation also shifts 16 bits of the hash code of key to the right and does bitwise XOR with the original hash code before doing the bitwise AND with (length - 1) to ensure that the effect of the higher order bits are also captured.

So, basically the point is, if the size is a power of two, the keys will be more evenly distributed across the array with minimal collision leading to better retrieval performance (and also less synchronizations in case of `ConcurrentHashMap`) when compared with any other size which is not a power of 2.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Saying that using powers of two make keys more evenly distributed is misleading, distribution is the same using % any number for size. The only reason is as you mentioned:  
`hash & (size - 1)` (which only will work with the power of 2 sizes) is faster than `hash % size`

Answer (score 6):

No matter what, you need to do a remainder operation to get a hash code (which can be any `int`) to map to an entry in the hash table.

In the case where `m` is a power of two -- and *only* that case -- `a % m` is equal to `a & (m - 1)`.  There is no other case in which remainders can be computed with `&`.

Comment: Is this true? I find this rather startling. Wouldn't this mean that when you resize the HashMap, everything key-value needs to be rehashed? I don't remember anything about expanding Hashtables, so if you say this is how it works, I won't question. I'm just a little startled. Also, if this is true, it means that designing a hashcode based on multiplication would probably perform rather poorly, as most hashcodes would be (a) to large, where only the last couple digits matter, and (b) even

Comment: Yes, of course everything needs to get rehashed.  You don't necessarily have to recompute all the hash codes if you stored them, but you absolutely do have to put everything in a new hash bucket.

Comment: (The result is that once every O(n) operations, you have to do O(n) work, which is still amortized O(1).)

Comment: To clarify for people not familiar with bit-manipulation, it is equivalent a decimal number modulus by power of 10 value. E.g. `1234 % 42` requires actual division by 42 to find the remainder, but `1234 % 100` is easily seen by taking the last two digit (34). As long as the divisor is a power of 10, you can just grab the last N digits, instead of having to perform a slow division operation. It the same for computers doing binary math, i.e. as long as divisor is a power of 2, the computer can simply grab (using bit masking) the last N bits.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two reasons:

1. Powers of two make time-complexity analysis easier because when talking about computation `log` is usually assumed to be base 2. (Note that in reality it can be shown that all `log` time complexities are equivalent regardless of the base, but it makes **reasoning** about the complexity easier if you use powers of 2 because your terms are all multiplying and dividing by 2)
2. Powers of two match the hardware nicely. Doubling a number in memory involves fewer operations than multiplying it by three. Similarly, pieces of memory are all sized in powers of two, so if you always double you can always occupy 2^n **full** bytes.